# Posicionar etiquetas al azar

Tags: javascript

Me interesa poder poner posiciones al azar de las etiquetas *span*, ya que tengo cuatro preguntas y la primera siempre es verdadera por lo mismo no puedo ponerla siempre en la primera posición ¿alguna idea de cómo lograrlo usando javascript?

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.tags{
width: 50%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tags > span{
width: 49%;
margin: 1px;
padding: 10px 0;
background-color: tomato;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
<span>Pregunta 1 y verdadera</span>
<span>Pregunta 2</span>
<span>Pregunta 3</span>
<span>Pregunta 4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Y si rellenas los span, con un vector el cual rellenas aleatoriamente?

Answer (score 3):

Esto funciona si solo tienes una pregunta y sus respectivas respuestas.

```js
var sp = document.querySelector('.tags');
for (var i = sp.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    sp.appendChild(sp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
```

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.tags{
width: 50%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tags > span{
width: 49%;
margin: 1px;
padding: 10px 0;
background-color: tomato;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
<span>Pregunta 1 y verdadera</span>
<span>Pregunta 2</span>
<span>Pregunta 3</span>
<span>Pregunta 4</span>
</div>
```

Esto funciona gracias al [Algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates), aprovechando que al agregar el elemento, realmente solo lo mueve de su posición original.

Finalmente una observación: El método que estás usando no es muy seguro, cualquiera que vea el código fuente de la página podrá identificar la respuesta correcta sin mucho problema, por lo que la mejor opción es "revolver" las respuestas del lado del servidor.

Comment: puedes explicar como funciona esto [Math.random() * i | 0]

Comment: @x-rw, el uso del [operador a nivel de bit](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators) `|` acompañado de cero, va a hacer que el resultado siempre sea 1 o cero.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la respuesta de @Triby es muy interesante, intente hacer algo con mas lineas y vaya que lo logre :)

voy insertando hasta encontrar numeros aleatoreos que no se repitan y que debe estar en un rango en este caso el minimo es 0 y el maximo es el tamaño del arreglo que contiene los spans, cada ves que se encuentra un numero aleatorio se concatena al div que tiene `id="tag`"

```js
let array1 = [];
array1.push("<span>Pregunta 1 y verdadera</span>");
array1.push("<span>Pregunta 2</span>");
array1.push("<span>Pregunta 3</span>");
array1.push("<span>Pregunta 4</span>");

let randoms = [];
let div = document.getElementById("tag");

while (randoms.length < array1.length) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array1.length - 1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
  if (randoms.indexOf(random) == -1) {
    randoms.push(random);
    div.innerHTML += array1[random];
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tags {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tags>span {
  width: 49%;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags" id="tag">

</div>
```